# How can I use Blender to learn about the influence of light on color

Tags: color, color-management, filmic-blender

I want to learn about how exactly light influences the color of objects because I want to be able to use that knowledge for painting. I tried using photographs and real world scenarios but those are much harder to manipulate to be the exact thing that I need. Then I thought Blender can render Photorealistic images so I should be able to learn from those. Now I have a simple scene with a Sphere and a Light Source and I generated random colors for the color of the sphere, the light and the background and used a color picker to see what happens. My problem is that I don't know if this even makes any sense and which view transform I should use because Standard and Filmic give wildly different results.

Comment: The Blender render engines provide visual simulations, but have different limitations, and none of them are currently suitable to your stated needs.  For example, what you're describing would need accurate caustics, which is in development but which Blender currently doesn't have outside of that.  This is only one of the many issues using Blender in the way you describe.

Comment: Hi :). You can experiment with lighting and materials the same way as in real world. It's a great way to learn how ligh works. What specifically are you stuck at? :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is an important question. You're looking to investigate "how does radiosity render engines work". You're looking to investigate "light dispersion on pbr materials" and you're looking to investigate "how do roughness maps work". Also, very important "What are PBR materials".

Blender can help you with all of the above questions PRACTICALLY, but you need to understand them from CONCEPT. Why do we need a metalness texture map? Why do we need to preserve energy on surfaces?

You can read / watch videos with the exact keywords I've described, and you can apply them to materials in Blender using the PRINCIPLED BSDF SHADER to a cube, a sphere, etc.. as 3d mesh.

You need a lot of "context background" for all the terminology we use in 3D first. That will take you into the rabbit hole of programming shaders and visual examples everywhere. Just as long as you understand what you're looking to achieve, (radiosity is an old term but it will help you in paint artist's common term-grounds), you'll understand these elements better:
CAMERA
LIGHT
SURFACE
SHADING
TRANSLUCENCY
And then it gets better because Blender can "stop" any calculation of the real-world parameters and do a custom render of what you need to achieve either by working in PASSES, shaders to arbitrary outputs, and a lot of advanced technical terms. You'll get there when you progress on your 3D journey.

I hope this helps with your question.